# how to add images to resourse/drawable folder in android project dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

how to add images to resource/drawable folder in android project dynamically ?

I shloud browse the in built gallery app in android phones and add images from gallery to resouse/drawable folder can it be done ?

> Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
>   intent.setType("image/*"); startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK);

i have used the above code for picking image from the gallery

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand your question better I have edited the answer.

No the app directory structure as exists in eclipse does not exist when the app is compiled and installed on the users phone.

However you can save them in a number of methods as outlined in [Data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

So for instance you can create a directory for your app on the SD card (external storage) and save them in there and give it the required permissions.

Comment: no I want to do it from my application ,I Want to browse the in built gallery folder and copy it to drawable folder dynamically

Comment: The gallery as in Android Gallery where photos and videos are stored from the user using the camera and saving pictures?

Answer (score 0):

No you cant save Image or Video in Resource folder after compiling the code you can save that either on SD Card or internal memory if you don't want user to get access on the once selected image you can save it in Internal memory(/data/data/Package Name/) of phone if your image size is not too large you can also save image in Database as BLOB.